# Crop YUV420/NV21 byte array directly in android

Tags: android, crop, libyuv

I need to crop every frame from the camera's onPreviewFrame. I want to crop it directly doing operations with the byte array without converting it to a bitmap. The reason I want to do it directly on the array is because it can't be too slow or too expensive. After the crop operation I will use the output byte array directly so I don't need any bitmap conversion.

```
int frameWidth;
int frameHeight;    

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // Crop the data array directly.

    cropData(data, frameWidth, frameHeight, startCropX, startCropY, outputWidth, outputHeight);

}
```

Comment: Are you asking for help with code you've written, or asking for someone to write code for you? If the former, show what you've tried and explain what doesn't work. If the latter, you might be in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static byte[] cropNV21(byte[] img, int imgWidth, @NonNull Rect cropRect) {
    // 1.5 mean 1.0 for Y and 0.25 each for U and V
    int croppedImgSize = (int)Math.floor(cropRect.width() * cropRect.height() * 1.5);
    byte[] croppedImg = new byte[croppedImgSize];

    // Start points of UV plane
    int imgYPlaneSize = (int)Math.ceil(img.length / 1.5);
    int croppedImgYPlaneSize = cropRect.width() * cropRect.height();

    // Y plane copy
    for (int w = 0; w < cropRect.height(); w++) {
        int imgPos = (cropRect.top + w) * imgWidth + cropRect.left;
        int croppedImgPos = w * cropRect.width();
        System.arraycopy(img, imgPos, croppedImg, croppedImgPos, cropRect.width());
    }

    // UV plane copy
    // U and V are reduced by 2 * 2, so each row is the same size as Y
    // and is half U and half V data, and there are Y_rows/2 of UV_rows
    for (int w = 0; w < (int)Math.floor(cropRect.height() / 2.0); w++) {
        int imgPos = imgYPlaneSize + (cropRect.top / 2 + w) * imgWidth + cropRect.left;
        int croppedImgPos = croppedImgYPlaneSize + (w * cropRect.width());
        System.arraycopy(img, imgPos, croppedImg, croppedImgPos, cropRect.width());
    }

    return croppedImg;
}
```

NV21 structure:

[image]

P.S.: Also, if the starting position of your rectangle is odd, the U and V will be swapped. To handle this case, I use:

```
    if (cropRect.left % 2 == 1) {
        cropRect.left -= 1;
    }
    if (cropRect.top % 2 == 1) {
        cropRect.top -= 1;
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me very well. Best solution amongst several I evaluated on StackOverflow. Thank you!

Comment: @Mattfromvision.app thank you for the feedback!

Comment: It worked perfectly, this is the perfect working cropping method I found so far. Thank you so much!